# AJAX sciprt loads posts from all categories in a single category view in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, posts

I have a function that dynamicaly loads more posts after clicking the button and a LoopHandler.php that is displaying posts. Everything works perfect, apart from that the loop is always displaying all of the posts. So if I am on the category page it displays posts from all of the categories. Why is it happening so? How to fix it?

```
// ajaxLoop.js
jQuery(function($){
    var page = 1;
    var loading = true;
    var $window = $(window);
    var $content = $("body #post-stream .block");
    var load_posts = function(posts, row){
            $.ajax({
                type       : "GET",
                data       : {numPosts : posts, pageNumber: page, postsInRow: row},
                dataType   : "html",
                url        : "../loopHandler.php",
                beforeSend : function(){
                    $content.append('<div id="temp_load" style="text-align:center; clear: both; padding: 30px 0;">\
                        <img src="http://cayennestudio.pl/segritta/wp-content/themes/segritta-ajax/css/img/ajax-loader.gif" />\
                        </div>');
                },
                success    : function(data){
                    $data = $(data);
                    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()-1);
                    if($data.length){
                        $data.hide();
                        $content.append($data);
                        $data.fadeIn(500, function(){
                            $("#temp_load").remove();
                            loading = false;
                        });
                    } else {
                        $("#temp_load").remove();
                    }
                },
                error     : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#temp_load").remove();
                    alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
                }
        });
        page++;
    }
    var load_szorts = function(posts, row){
            $.ajax({
                type       : "GET",
                data       : {numPosts : posts, pageNumber: page, postsInRow: row},
                dataType   : "html",
                url        : "http://cayennestudio.pl/segritta/wp-content/themes/segritta-ajax/loopHandlerSzorts.php",
                beforeSend : function(){
                },
                success    : function(data){
                    $data = $(data);
                    $data.hide();
                    $content.append($data);
                    $data.fadeIn(500, function(){
                        loading = false;
                    });
                },
                error     : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
                }
        });
        page++;
    }
    if ( $('body.home').length ) {
        load_posts(4, 2);
        $('.load-more').click(function(){
            load_posts(4, 2);
        }); 
    };
    if ( $('body.category').length ) {
        load_posts(9, 3);
        $('.load-more').click(function(){
            load_posts(9, 3);
        });
    };
    if ( $('body.post-type-archive-szort').length ) {
        load_szorts(8, 4);
        $('.load-more').click(function(){
            load_szorts(4, 4);
        });
    };
});
```

LoopHandler.php

```
<?php
// Our include
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

// Our variables
    $numPosts = (isset($_GET['numPosts'])) ? $_GET['numPosts'] : 0;
    $page = (isset($_GET['pageNumber'])) ? $_GET['pageNumber'] : 0;

    query_posts(array(
           'posts_per_page' => $numPosts,
           'paged'          => $page,
    ));

    global $var_counter;
    global $var_row;
    $var_counter = 0;
    $var_row = (isset($_GET['postsInRow'])) ? $_GET['postsInRow'] : 2;

// our loop
    if ( have_posts() ) :

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;

    else:

        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

    endif;

    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: please narrow down your problem...is issue server side or client side?

Comment: Server side - my loop is displaying all the posts, even on a category page. I would like to display only posts from current category on a category page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it should go to WordPress.StackExchange, I guess.

And going back to your problem...

### First problem: Bad AJAX handling

You shouldn't create your own PHP files to process AJAX requests in WordPress. WP has it's own mechanisms to process AJAX requests and you should use them for compatibility reasons.

You can read more on this topic here: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

You just need to create a filter with correct name and call AJAX requests with correct `action` value...

### Second Problem: Always all posts

You don't pass current category anywhere in your AJAX request and you don't put it in your WP_Query.

You should pass current category ID in your AJAX request like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type       : "GET",
    data       : {numPosts : posts, pageNumber: page, postsInRow: row, currentCat: currentCat}, // of course you need to make sure that currentCat variable contains the ID of current category or 0 otherwise
    dataType   : "html",
    ...
```

And then process it in your PHP code like so:

```
$args = array(
       'posts_per_page' => $numPosts,
       'paged'          => $page,
);
if ( isset($_GET['currentCat']) && $_GET['currentCat'] ) {
    $args['cat'] = $_GET['currentCat'];
}
query_posts($args);
```